# Memcached performance drops with to-be-cached value sizes being small

Tags: java, memcached, spymemcached

I just started to use memcached. We use spymemcached java client via a Pajamas Proxy server (all with default setting and 1024 mb memory allocated). Setting the program to access memcached is very simple and straightforward, but I have one observation though:

when the cached value size drops to a certain point (in my case: about 1450 bytes), the performance drops dramatically (from 4 msecs to 200 msecs each retrieval).

Does this mean that the value that I want to cache has to be above certain sizes? How would I be able to determine such sizes?
Thanks in advance!

David

Comment: Where are you measuring these latencies from?

Answer (score 1):

Could Nagle's algorithm (TCP delaying the sending of small packets for a while) be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

While I don't know much about memcached internals,it seems to me that it has to do with the memory allocation management. Memcached maintains memory pools in different chunk sizes. http://www.mikeperham.com/2009/06/22/slabs-pages-chunks-and-memcached/ . So mostly you are facing internal fragmentaion,and memcached has to look at two chunks to lookup your data.

Comment: I understand that, but if this is the case, the performance should drop rather than improve when the cached value sizes increase, right?